# So much problems with Eclipse developing for Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

a million error per day using eclipse with the Android plug-in i tried everything uninstall plug-in ,eclipse,JDK,JRE and install them again and using different ver. also changes Workspaces , i thought the problem with the new Java and Eclipse but i solved it and still . what the alternative is there a way so it could be more stable is other IDE with Android Plugin is mature enough to use them instead of all the problem and headache that eclipse give me in my life .

Edit: i use Eclipse 3.5 and im running Win7 in 4 Gig of ram ,i read the info about the known bug with Eclipse and JDK 6 update 21 and try what they suggest but i think thats not the problem.

some of the problem that i had ,XML editor for Android also sometime the disable of the Auto-complete (i made new Workspaces now i have 10's of them ) and when i open the DDMS nothing appears even when i try to add the LogCat also alot of error msgs that prompt to me and close the IDE and sometime it just close by-itself  .

Edit 2 : New Error it display to me "permGen space" ?!

Comment: Sounds frustrating. I've been real pleased with Android development on eclipse. If you don't mind me asking, what OS/hardware are you running on, and what are the specific errors you are receiving?

Comment: What kind of problems ? Any details ? Which Eclipse version ?

Comment: please see my edit to the question i added some of the problems that i have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of Eclipse are you using?

The ADT Plugin for Eclipse site warns about this:

> Caution: There are known issues with
>   the ADT plugin running with Eclipse
>   3.6. Please stay on 3.5 until further notice.

Also, check your JDK to be the latest. If you are on Windows, there's [a known bug with Eclipse and JDK 6 update 21](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Oracle.2FSun_VM_1.6.0_21_on_Windows). Check that you are using the latest version since Oracle fixed it.

Must add I've used Eclipse for Java Developers version 3.5 with the ADT plugin, and haven't had any of the mentioned problems so far.

**EDIT:** Could you be more specific with those errors?

XML editor for Android works fine with auto-complete in my case, so does the debugger. I've been able to debug applications correctly. Take in consideration when launching the emulator, it takes a few minutes for the emulated system to boot, launch your app, etc.

You should copy and paste the error messages that Eclipse displays, in order to have an idea of what is happening.

It could be a problem with the memory assigned to Eclipse, the JVM, or who knows what, but we need more detailed information in order to assist you.

**EDIT 2:** This is quite a common error in Eclipse. From [Eclipse's Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F):

> If you see java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   PermGen space errors, you need to
>   increase the permanent generation
>   space available to Eclipse.
>
> PermGen is the permanent generation of
>   objects in the VM (Class names,
>   internalized strings, objects that
>   will never get garbage-collected). An
>   easy, if somewhat memory-hungry fix is
>   to enlarge the maximum space for these
>   objects by adding

```
eclipse [normal arguments] -vmargs -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M [more VM args]
```

> The arguments after -vmargs are
>   directly passed to the VM. Run java -X
>   for the list of options your VM
>   accepts. Options starting with -X are
>   implementation-specific and may not be
>   applicable to all VMs.
>
> You can also put the extra options in
>   eclipse.ini.

Check the link for further information, you can find common errors and bugs in the **Eclipse and Sun VMs on Windows** part.

Comment: Thanks , but i tried all the above before i asked here and nothing seems to work . please see my edit to the question.

Comment: the problem that most of what happen coz the close the eclipse without display any error msg but i'll try to disply what i got as soon that i have it .

Answer (score 1):

I'm truly sorry for saying this, and I'll probably will be shot to death by it... but:
On every other development environment I've used in Python, Ruby on Rails, PHP <> MySQL, Java, and... all have been working best on Windows operating systems.

It was a surprise to me that Android really works best on Mac OS. Lets face it, I'm a Windows kind of guy, but for Android - Mac is your choice!

Sorry...

Comment: I recently finished a fairly large android project, and everything was pretty flawless. Oh, and I was on Windows 7 x64

Comment: i run also Win7 X64 but i dont know whats wrong ! but all the developer that i work with are using Mac and they have no problem with it !

Answer (score 0):

A million errors per day sounds like some component is severely broken.  Is the Android plugin the right version for the Eclipse version you are using.  There are many which are not yet ready for Eclipse 3.6

Answer (score 0):

I did not have any problem getting the SDK up and running on ubuntu. Its free, the resources are great, and most of all its not windows. So linking libraries and stuff is not that big a headache. Also its much more light on your computer so you have all the power that your awesome pc has to test really heavy apps! Why don't you give it a shot? I bet you will not be disappointed. ;-)

Comment: Oh btw I use a mac book with Ubuntu being the sole OS on it and I love it. When you want to play around with adb shell, you have the Ubuntu file-structure and the terminal both of which are an added advantage. You might want to give it a try. Also my firm uses Ubuntu for development of android.

Comment: Ubuntu running on mac hardware that seems the prefect combination , i'll keep that in my mind and try at least install Ubuntu on my device . Thanks :)